# Adding surrounding double quotes to each noteproperty of an array (i think)

Tags: arrays, sqlite, powershell

I really am having no luck with this so excuse my lack of failed code examples to show.

I have an array that i am passing to an SQLite database mounted as a psdrive using the SQLite module. the destination table (db:\events) was created with the following commands and definition:

```
mount-sqlite -name dbRAM -dataSource :memory:
Invoke-Item dbRAM: -sql 'CREATE TABLE event (timestamp DATETIME PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,event NOT NULL,data3 TEXT,data4 TEXT,data5 TEXT,data6 TEXT,data7 TEXT,data8 TEXT,data9 TEXT);'
```

This created a child item of the following:

```
PS dbRAM:\> gci


SSItemMode       : d+~<     i
PSPath           : CodeOwls.PowerShell.SQLite.Provider\SQLite::[Data Source=:memory:]\event
PSParentPath     : CodeOwls.PowerShell.SQLite.Provider\SQLite::[Data Source=:memory:]
PSChildName      : event
PSDrive          : dbRAM
PSProvider       : CodeOwls.PowerShell.SQLite.Provider\SQLite
PSIsContainer    : True
TABLE_CATALOG    : main
TABLE_SCHEMA     : 
TABLE_NAME       : event
TABLE_TYPE       : table
TABLE_ID         : 1
TABLE_ROOTPAGE   : 2
TABLE_DEFINITION : CREATE TABLE event (timestamp DATETIME PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,event NOT NULL,data3 TEXT,data4 TEXT,data5 TEXT,data6 TEXT,data7 TEXT,data8 TEXT,data9 TEXT)
RowError         : 
RowState         : Unchanged
Table            : {event}
ItemArray        : {main, , event, table...}
HasErrors        : False
```

I have an array created through Convertfrom-Json that came from the best game ever this century called Elite: Dangerous. The problem however is that there are only a couple of sql columns that i can actually predict the name of. These are the timestamp and event property names.   Here is ONE example of my array:

```
PS dbRAM:\> $EliteEvent |gm


   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name                        MemberType   Definition                                    
----                        ----------   ----------                                    
Equals                      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                
GetHashCode                 Method       int GetHashCode()                             
GetType                     Method       type GetType()                                
ToString                    Method       string ToString()                             
event                       NoteProperty string event=Docked                           
StarSystem                  NoteProperty string StarSystem=Laksak                      
StationEconomy              NoteProperty string StationEconomy=$economy_Colony;        
StationEconomy_Localised    NoteProperty string StationEconomy_Localised=Colony        
StationFaction              NoteProperty string StationFaction=Lei Cheung              
StationGovernment           NoteProperty string StationGovernment=$government_Engineer;
StationGovernment_Localised NoteProperty string StationGovernment_Localised=Workshop   
StationName                 NoteProperty string StationName=Trader's Rest              
timestamp                   NoteProperty string timestamp=2017-02-26 04:07:54
```

I can see 2 problems with this and the following error message will support that.  The first being that there are no quotes around the values so i need to find a way of adding quotes around each value within the array as documented at https://psqlite.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20Records&referringTitle=Documentation

If i try to copy this array to the sql i get the following error:

```
PS dbRAM:\> new-item -path dbRAM:\event $EliteEvent
New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '@{timestamp=2017-02-26 04:07:54; event=Docked; StationName=Trader's Rest; StarSystem=Laksak; StationFaction=Lei Cheung; 
StationGovernment=$government_Engineer;; StationGovernment_Localised=Workshop; StationEconomy=$economy_Colony;; StationEconomy_Localised=Colony}'.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-item -path dbRAM:\event $EliteEvent
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

The second huge and major issue is that i just want to drop the property values in to my properties data3 to data9 but i never know what the names of the different properties in the array will be.  Each event type produces its own set of data, again the only thing in common between these types is the timestamp and the event type.  How on earth can i populated the name unknown properties in sequence to my SQL via an array used in the new-item cmdlet ?

In case you wonder what is the point of losing the property names i will be pulling data back out of the database and handling the other properties by code that detects the event type and then processes the data according to the fixed format associated to that type.

Really am at my wits end trying to get through this problem and i hope someone can help.

Is this really just too much to be able to achieve ?

Kindest regards !

**Edit*****

I thought about what it would mean to create a different table definition for each type of event and process them separately so i created a table to exactly fit the array property names:

```
PS dbRAM:\> Invoke-Item dbRAM: -sql 'CREATE TABLE event_docked (timestamp DATETIME PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,event TEXT NOT NULL,StarSystem TEXT,StationEconomy TEXT,StationEconomy_Localised TEXT,StationFaction TEXT, StationGovernment TEXT,StationGovernment_Localised TEXT,StationName TEXT);'
```

Same problem is persistent:

```
PS dbRAM:\> new-item -path dbRAM:\event_docked $EliteEvent
New-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '@{timestamp=2017-02-26 04:07:54; event=Docked; StationName=Trader's Rest; StarSystem=Laksak; StationFaction=Lei Cheung; StationGovernment=$government_Engineer;; StationGovernment_Localised=Workshop; StationEconomy=$economy_Colony;; StationEconomy_Localised=Colony}'.
At line:1 char:1
+ new-item -path dbRAM:\event_docked $EliteEvent
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

****edit**  extra information in regards to suggestion below by  Mathias R. Jessen

```
PS dbRAM:\> $EliteEvent | New-Item -Path dbRAM:\event_docked
New-Item : Sequence contains no elements
At line:1 char:15
+ $EliteEvent | New-Item -Path dbRAM:\event_docked
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ([Data Source=:memory:]\event_docked:String) [New-Item], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItem.Invoke,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand


PS dbRAM:\> $EliteEvent


timestamp                   : 2017-02-26 04:07:54
event                       : Docked
StationName                 : Trader's Rest
StarSystem                  : Laksak
StationFaction              : Lei Cheung
StationGovernment           : $government_Engineer;
StationGovernment_Localised : Workshop
StationEconomy              : $economy_Colony;
StationEconomy_Localised    : Colony
```

****edit** extra information in response to next suggestion below:

```
$JournalPath = "\\AORUS_X7\EliteDangerousLogs"
import-module sqlite
New-PSDrive -Name Journal -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $JournalPath
function Get-EliteEvent
    {
      $Event = convertfrom-json (Get-ChildItem -Path $JournalPath -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -last 1 | select-object $_.fullname | get-content | select-object -last 1)
      $Event.timestamp = $Event.timestamp.Replace('T', ' ')
      $Event.timestamp = $Event.timestamp.TrimEnd('Z')
      return $Event
    }

mount-sqlite -name dbRAM -dataSource :memory:
Invoke-Item dbRAM: -sql 'CREATE TABLE event_docked (timestamp DATETIME PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,event TEXT NOT NULL,StarSystem TEXT,StationEconomy TEXT,StationEconomy_Localised TEXT,StationFaction TEXT, StationGovernment TEXT,StationGovernment_Localised TEXT,StationName TEXT);'

$EliteEvent = Get-EliteEvent
```

above is scripted - then i run following commands at the prompt:

```
PS dbRAM:\> $EliteEvent | New-Item -Path dbRAM:\event_docked
New-Item : Sequence contains no elements
At line:1 char:15
+ $EliteEvent | New-Item -Path dbRAM:\event_docked
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ([Data Source=:memory:]\event_docked:String) [New-Item], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItem.Invoke,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand


PS dbRAM:\> $EliteEvent


timestamp                   : 2017-02-26 04:07:54
event                       : Docked
StationName                 : Trader's Rest
StarSystem                  : Laksak
StationFaction              : Lei Cheung
StationGovernment           : $government_Engineer;
StationGovernment_Localised : Workshop
StationEconomy              : $economy_Colony;
StationEconomy_Localised    : Colony
```

There is a directory full of json files and the above function takes the last line from the last file.  Here is the output of the command from the function on the commandline (without the convertfrom-json)

```
PS C:\Users\Stuart\Desktop\Amy-EVA2_git (master ≡)
$ Get-ChildItem -Path $JournalPath -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | Select-Object -last 1 | select-object $_.fullname | get-content | select-object -last 1
{ "timestamp":"2017-02-26T04:07:54Z", "event":"Docked", "StationName":"Trader's Rest", "StarSystem":"Laksak", "StationFaction":"Lei Cheung", "StationGovernment":"$government_Engineer; ", "StationGovernment_Localised":"Workshop", "StationEconomy":"$economy_Colony;", "StationEconomy_Localised":"Colony" }
```

However... somehow, i just checked and your command structure for the array pipe to new-item has worked this time, despite the error saying sequence contains no elements.  i dont understand it  (will accept it though and just turn off the errors)  check this out:

```
PS dbRAM:\> cd event_docked

PS dbRAM:\event_docked> dir


SSItemMode                  :   ~<>     
PSPath                      : CodeOwls.PowerShell.SQLite.Provider\SQLite::[Data Source=:memory:]\event_docked\26-02-2017 04:07:54
PSParentPath                : CodeOwls.PowerShell.SQLite.Provider\SQLite::[Data Source=:memory:]\event_docked
PSChildName                 : 26-02-2017 04:07:54
PSDrive                     : dbRAM
PSProvider                  : CodeOwls.PowerShell.SQLite.Provider\SQLite
PSIsContainer               : False
timestamp                   : 26/02/2017 04:07:54
event                       : Docked
StarSystem                  : Laksak
StationEconomy              : $economy_Colony;
StationEconomy_Localised    : Colony
StationFaction              : Lei Cheung
StationGovernment           : $government_Engineer;
StationGovernment_Localised : Workshop
StationName                 : Trader's Rest
RowError                    : 
RowState                    : Unchanged
Table                       : {26-02-2017 04:07:54}
ItemArray                   : {26/02/2017 04:07:54, Docked, Laksak, $economy_Colony;...}
HasErrors                   : False
```

its working, i dont know how, any idea what happened or do i accept it and suppress the errors ?  thanks so much for your help so far.

Comment: Do i have to create a different table to fit every event type ?

Comment: Have you tried the syntax shown on codeplex? `$EliteEvent | New-Item -Path dbRAM:\event_docked`

Comment: Just did as you suggested - there are several different ways of structuring the command documented on codeplex and i tried some different variations.  The error is slightly different using your suggestion and even more unexpected than my original commands.  piping the array at the new-item cmdlet gives an error from new-item saying "sequence contains no elements"  i will create an edit to the original post to show exact commands and output.  thanks for your input :)

Comment: Can you maybe show exactly how you obtain `$EliteEvent`? The original JSON and the exact command you used to convert it to objects?

Comment: Ok thanks - i will make another edit and add the code

Comment: added extra information

Comment: Is there a StackOverflow badge for the longest question ?  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'this' case the answer was when you want to create a new record in an SQLite database using the SQLite powershell module then it worked by piping the array at the new-item cmdlet.

in 'this' case it did produce an error but it was not critical as the data was inserted in to the SQLite record correctly and so i just redirected the error output to null.